# website orientation on mobile browsers

Tags: html, ipad, responsive-design, orientation

Hmm.. I am not sure how to describe this. But I will try

So say you have iPad and it is in 0 degree position, you have your website layout for that position, and then when the user rotate the iPad to 90 degree, it changed the orientation. Basically now the website layout has to change too. But I don't know how to adjust it to fit the new layout. Do we have to re-calculate the width of website layout, etc? Or is there a better way to do it? I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: The browser does this for you. All you need to do is ensure that your website is viewable at multiple resolutions, and you won't have to worry about the actual transition.

Comment: hmm... here is what i am struggling 
the ipad in portrait orientation is 768×946, and in landscape is 1024×690. so i have a website that fills out to 768px, but then when it is landscape it stretched to 1024px and it does not look good at all. and it is even worse if the website is build for the landscape and then it got cut off when it is in the potrait.
So I guess what is the best practices? Do we build for potrait first? or the landscape first?

Comment: Oh... seems I misinterpreted your question. Sorry. The answers here are good though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I recommend to tackle this is using techniques found in [responsive web design](http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples/)

The basic is you will want to ensure you aren't using fixed size elements (e.g. em, %, etc) as much as possible along side [media-queries](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to detect your screen orientation and size.

This concept should get you on the right path, good luck!

Comment: Cool. I am going to take a look at this. I am not worried about the coding part but I am trying to find and grasp the concept first. Thanks.

Comment: I figured that much, hence no actual code in the answer. Good luck and if you find this to be the best answer don't forget to accept it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

Comment: hmm.. I saw this a lot. but what do we put in potrait.css and what in the landscape.css. Any code samples that I can play around? Thanks.

Comment: You write the css based on the width you want the site to display. You question is too generic for examples. You might want to start here: ( http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/responsive-web-design-a-visual-guide/)

Comment: Does this technique work if orientation changes after the page is loaded?